# Concatenate multiple row into single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT     
   RESVID, VEHTYPE
FROM         
   (SELECT     
       dbo.T_VEH_VEHRESERVATION.RESVID,
       TABLEVEHICLE.VEHTYPE, TABLEVEHICLE.VEHREGID
    FROM          
       (SELECT     
            dbo.T_VEH_VEHCATEGORY.VEHBRANDNAME + N' ' + dbo.T_VEH_VEHCLASS.VEHCLASSNAME AS VEHTYPE, 
            dbo.T_VEH_VEHREGISTRATION.VEHREGID
        FROM          
            dbo.T_VEH_VEHCATEGORY 
        WHERE      
            (dbo.T_VEH_VEHREGISTRATION.DELIND = 0) 
       ) AS TABLEVEHICLE 
    INNER JOIN
       dbo.T_VEH_VEHRESERVATION ON TABLEVEHICLE.VEHREGID = dbo.T_VEH_VEHRESERVATION.VEHREGID )
    GROUP BY 
       dbo.T_VEH_VEHRESERVATION.RESVID   
   ) AS TABLERESV
```

[image]

I would like to concatenate the `RESVID`: 33 (duplicate row) into 1.

This is just an example, of course what I Want is every duplicate row with this situation will be solved.

I try the XML PATH function, but does not work at all, and I have no idea what goes wrong, i will be appreciate if any help me on my code, and give me explanation on that.

My desire result:

```
RESVID   |  VEHTYPE
-------------------
  33     |  Proton Economic, Toyota Mid-size SUV
```

and i have only one table on my view

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this....

```
Select Distinct  RESVID ,Stuff((Select ','+VEHTYPE from TabelName A where A.RESVID =B.RESVID 
 For Xml Path('')),1,1,'') as VEHTYPE from TabelName B
```

Comment: Hi there, thank for your reply, this method i have tried, but always get sql execution error. Mostly having problems near 'where'. What cause this error? Thanks

Comment: SELECT     RESVID, STUFF(( SELECT ', ' +  VEHTYPE FROM TABLERESV A WHERE (A.VEHREGID = B.VEHREGID) FOR XML PATH('')), 1,2, '') AS VEHTYPE FROM TABLERESV B

Comment: try A.RESVID= B.RESVID like this....here sql fiddle demo...http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f53e4/3

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31902/discussion-between-taekiewzz-and-amitsingh)

Comment: i can not chat i m in office

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT     RESVID, STUFF(( SELECT ', ' +  VEHTYPE from TABLERESV A WHERE (A.RESVID = B.RESVID) FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1, '') as VEHTYPE FROM TABLERESV B

Comment: @taekiewzz whats the problem with this//

Comment: WHERE A.RESVID = B.RESVID try like this

Comment: same problem happen, so is it error happen because i put all the query your given on the first line and nothing change with those following line as i state in my question.

Comment: @taekiewzz plss show whole query you are runing or better you provide sqlfiddle for example www.sqlfiddle.com...create table and show what query you are runnig here

Comment: finally i get it right, i have no idea why but i think because at first as i did it within 1 table, the resvid is a FK, it cause many to many relationship, when i use the resvid in my parent table, it run smmothly, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try with STUFF()

```
SELECT RESVID ,
    STUFF((
    SELECT ','+ VEHTYPE    
    FROM TABLERESV b    
    WHERE a.RESVID = b.RESVID 
    FOR XML PATH('')
    )
    ,1,1,'') AS VEHTYPE
FROM TABLERESV  a
GROUP BY a.RESVID
```

Answer (score 1):

trY this:

```
SELECT B.resvid, STUFF(
(SELECT ',' + A.vehtype
FROM TABLE_NAME A
WHERE A.resvid=B.resvid
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS CSV
FROM TABLE_NAME B
GROUP BY B.resvid
```